# Enter a break into a formula

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I have a currently working formula.

Unfortunately, I need the second half of it to happen after the first half but they are happening at the same time currently.

I tried putting in :

```
Utilities.sleep(1000);
```

but that doesn't fix it.

I'm sure there must be an easy line that makes something happen after?

```
function onOpen() {
var bb = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var ssId = bb.getId();
var sheet = bb.getSheetByName('IR');
sheet.getRange('B1').setValue(ssId); 


var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('IR');       
var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName('Topsheet');
sheet.getRange('A2').copyTo(sheet1.getRange('A1'), {contentsOnly:true})
}
```

Note: 
I have to have it all in one formula as triggers don't copy when you copy a file and this will be copied a lot by my whole team.

Will

Comment: Let me guess, you want to force formula recalculation before the `copyTo` bit...

Comment: Basically, the first part of the formula enters the file ID into sheer IR cell B1. I then use a formula in Sheet IR cell A2 to add words in front / behind it. I then want to take the (value only) from A2 and move it to sheet Topsheet cell A1. The issue is the value of IR - A2 is being moved before the file ID is inputted into IR - A1

Comment: That's basically what I wanted to do. You are the man you have saved me hours of headache and frustration. Should I delete the whole post now?